# Android Fragment Change

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, fragment

How to change Fragment i.e change using back camera to usb camera for tensorflow as input for object detection,i suppose its possible by changing the fragment in the camera activity for full code :
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/66f60ebc3dd2e8527b7bbbb280fe0657d54f20f4/lite/examples/object_detection/android

for usb camera:
https://github.com/quantum6/Android-USB-OTG-Camera

```
 

import com.jiangdg.usbcamera.R;
import com.jiangdg.usbcamera.UVCCameraHelper;
import com.jiangdg.usbcamera.utils.FileUtils;
import com.serenegiant.usb.CameraDialog;
import com.serenegiant.usb.Size;
import com.serenegiant.usb.USBMonitor;
import com.serenegiant.usb.common.AbstractUVCCameraHandler;
import com.serenegiant.usb.widget.CameraViewInterface;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class camo extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraDialog.CameraDialogParent  {

    @BindView(R.id.camera_view1)
    public View mTextureView;

    private boolean isRequest;
    private boolean isPreview;


    private UVCCameraHelper mCameraHelper;
    private CameraViewInterface mUVCCameraView;
    private AlertDialog mDialog;


    private UVCCameraHelper.OnMyDevConnectListener listener = new UVCCameraHelper.OnMyDevConnectListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAttachDev(UsbDevice device) {
            // request open permission
            if (!isRequest) {
                isRequest = true;

                if (mCameraHelper != null) {
                    mCameraHelper.requestPermission(0);

                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onDettachDev(UsbDevice device) {
            // close camera
            if (isRequest) {
                isRequest = false;
                mCameraHelper.closeCamera();
                showShortMsg(device.getDeviceName() + " is out");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectDev(UsbDevice device, boolean isConnected) {
            if (!isConnected) {
                showShortMsg("fail to connect,please check resolution params");
                isPreview = false;
            } else {
                isPreview = true;
                showShortMsg("connecting");

                // need to wait UVCCamera initialize over
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Looper.prepare();
                        if(mCameraHelper != null && mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened()) {

                        }
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisConnectDev(UsbDevice device) {
            showShortMsg("disconnecting");
        }

    };

    @Override
    public USBMonitor getUSBMonitor() {
        return mCameraHelper.getUSBMonitor();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDialogResult(boolean canceled) {
        if (canceled) {
            showShortMsg("取消操作");
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camo);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);



        mUVCCameraView = (CameraViewInterface) mTextureView;
        mUVCCameraView.setCallback(mCallback);
        mCameraHelper = UVCCameraHelper.getInstance();


        mCameraHelper.setDefaultFrameFormat(UVCCameraHelper.FRAME_FORMAT_MJPEG);

        mCameraHelper.initUSBMonitor(this, mUVCCameraView, listener);


        mCameraHelper.setOnPreviewFrameListener(new AbstractUVCCameraHandler.OnPreViewResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewResult(byte[] nv21Yuv) {
                Log.d("debug", "onPreviewResult: "+nv21Yuv.length);

            }
        });


    }


    private CameraViewInterface.Callback mCallback = new CameraViewInterface.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(CameraViewInterface view, Surface surface) {
            // must have
            if (!isPreview && mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened()) {
                mCameraHelper.startPreview(mUVCCameraView);
                isPreview = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(CameraViewInterface view, Surface surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroy(CameraViewInterface view, Surface surface) {
            // must have
            if (isPreview && mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened()) {
                mCameraHelper.stopPreview();
                isPreview = false;
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // step.2 register USB event broadcast
        if (mCameraHelper != null) {
            mCameraHelper.registerUSB();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // step.3 unregister USB event broadcast
        if (mCameraHelper != null) {
            mCameraHelper.unregisterUSB();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        FileUtils.releaseFile();
        // step.4 release uvc camera resources
        if (mCameraHelper != null) {
            mCameraHelper.release();
        }
    }
    public boolean isCameraOpened() {
        return mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened();
    }
   


}
```

From the above code i must use usb camera instead of back camera the above is the usb camera class,,

CameraActivity:

```
protected void setFragment() {
    String cameraId = chooseCamera();

    Fragment fragment;
    if (useCamera2API) {
      CameraConnectionFragment camera2Fragment =
              CameraConnectionFragment.newInstance(
                      new CameraConnectionFragment.ConnectionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPreviewSizeChosen(final Size size, final int rotation) {
                          previewHeight = size.getHeight();
                          previewWidth = size.getWidth();
                          CameraActivity.this.onPreviewSizeChosen(size, rotation);
                        }
                      },
                      this,
                      getLayoutId(),
                      getDesiredPreviewFrameSize());

      camera2Fragment.setCamera(cameraId);
      fragment = camera2Fragment;
    } else {
      fragment =
              new LegacyCameraConnectionFragment(this, getLayoutId(), getDesiredPreviewFrameSize());
    }

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
  }
```

CameraConnectionFragment:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class CameraConnectionFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();

  /**
   * The camera preview size will be chosen to be the smallest frame by pixel size capable of
   * containing a DESIRED_SIZE x DESIRED_SIZE square.
   */
  private static final int MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE = 320;

  /** Conversion from screen rotation to JPEG orientation. */
  private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

  private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

  static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
  }

  /** A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera. */
  private final Semaphore cameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
  /** A {@link OnImageAvailableListener} to receive frames as they are available. */
  private final OnImageAvailableListener imageListener;
  /** The input size in pixels desired by TensorFlow (width and height of a square bitmap). */
  private final Size inputSize;
  /** The layout identifier to inflate for this Fragment. */
  private final int layout;

  private final ConnectionCallback cameraConnectionCallback;
  private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback =
      new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureProgressed(
            final CameraCaptureSession session,
            final CaptureRequest request,
            final CaptureResult partialResult) {}

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(
            final CameraCaptureSession session,
            final CaptureRequest request,
            final TotalCaptureResult result) {}
      };
 
  private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback =
      new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(final CameraDevice cd) {
          // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
          cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
          cameraDevice = cd;
          createCameraPreviewSession();
        }


        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(final CameraDevice cd) {
          cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
          cd.close();
          cameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final CameraDevice cd, final int error) {
          cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
          cd.close();
          cameraDevice = null;
          final Activity activity = getActivity();
          if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
          }
        }
      };
  /**
   * {@link TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener} handles several lifecycle events on a {@link
   * TextureView}.
   */
  private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener =
      new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(
            final SurfaceTexture texture, final int width, final int height) {
          openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(
            final SurfaceTexture texture, final int width, final int height) {
          configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(final SurfaceTexture texture) {
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(final SurfaceTexture texture) {}
      };

  private CameraConnectionFragment(
      final ConnectionCallback connectionCallback,
      final OnImageAvailableListener imageListener,
      final int layout,
      final Size inputSize) {
    this.cameraConnectionCallback = connectionCallback;
    this.imageListener = imageListener;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.inputSize = inputSize;
  }

  
  protected static Size chooseOptimalSize(final Size[] choices, final int width, final int height) {
    final int minSize = Math.max(Math.min(width, height), MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE);
    final Size desiredSize = new Size(width, height);

    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    boolean exactSizeFound = false;
    final List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
    final List<Size> tooSmall = new ArrayList<Size>();
    for (final Size option : choices) {
      if (option.equals(desiredSize)) {
        // Set the size but don't return yet so that remaining sizes will still be logged.
        exactSizeFound = true;
      }

      if (option.getHeight() >= minSize && option.getWidth() >= minSize) {
        bigEnough.add(option);
      } else {
        tooSmall.add(option);
      }
    }

    LOGGER.i("Desired size: " + desiredSize + ", min size: " + minSize + "x" + minSize);
    LOGGER.i("Valid preview sizes: [" + TextUtils.join(", ", bigEnough) + "]");
    LOGGER.i("Rejected preview sizes: [" + TextUtils.join(", ", tooSmall) + "]");

    if (exactSizeFound) {
      LOGGER.i("Exact size match found.");
      return desiredSize;
    }

    // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
      final Size chosenSize = Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
      LOGGER.i("Chosen size: " + chosenSize.getWidth() + "x" + chosenSize.getHeight());
      return chosenSize;
    } else {
      LOGGER.e("Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
      return choices[0];
    }
  }

  public static CameraConnectionFragment newInstance(
      final ConnectionCallback callback,
      final OnImageAvailableListener imageListener,
      final int layout,
      final Size inputSize) {
    return new CameraConnectionFragment(callback, imageListener, layout, inputSize);
  }

  /**
   * Shows a {@link Toast} on the UI thread.
   *
   * @param text The message to show
   */
  private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(
          new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });
    }
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();

    // When the screen is turned off and turned back on, the SurfaceTexture is already
    // available, and "onSurfaceTextureAvailable" will not be called. In that case, we can open
    // a camera and start preview from here (otherwise, we wait until the surface is ready in
    // the SurfaceTextureListener).
    if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
      openCamera(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
    } else {
      textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
  }

  public void setCamera(String cameraId) {
    this.cameraId = cameraId;
  }

  /** Sets up member variables related to camera. */
  private void setUpCameraOutputs() {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
      final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

      final StreamConfigurationMap map =
          characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

      sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

      // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
      // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
      // garbage capture data.
      previewSize =
          chooseOptimalSize(
              map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
              inputSize.getWidth(),
              inputSize.getHeight());

      // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
      final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
      if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
      } else {
        textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.getHeight(), previewSize.getWidth());
      }
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
    } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
      // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
      // device this code runs.
      ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.tfe_od_camera_error))
          .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
      throw new IllegalStateException(getString(R.string.tfe_od_camera_error));
    }

    cameraConnectionCallback.onPreviewSizeChosen(previewSize, sensorOrientation);
  }

  /** Opens the camera specified by {@link CameraConnectionFragment#cameraId}. */
  private void openCamera(final int width, final int height) {
    setUpCameraOutputs();
    configureTransform(width, height);
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
      if (!cameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
      }
      manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
  }

  /** Closes the current {@link CameraDevice}. */
  private void closeCamera() {
    try {
      cameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
      if (null != captureSession) {
        captureSession.close();
        captureSession = null;
      }
      if (null != cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
      }
      if (null != previewReader) {
        previewReader.close();
        previewReader = null;
      }
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
      cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
  }

  /** Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
  private void startBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("ImageListener");
    backgroundThread.start();
    backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
  }

  /** Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
  private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
      backgroundThread.join();
      backgroundThread = null;
      backgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
    }
  }

  /** Creates a new {@link CameraCaptureSession} for camera preview. */
  private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
      final SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
      assert texture != null;

      // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
      texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());

      // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
      final Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

      // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
      previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
      previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

      LOGGER.i("Opening camera preview: " + previewSize.getWidth() + "x" + previewSize.getHeight());

      // Create the reader for the preview frames.
      previewReader =
          ImageReader.newInstance(
              previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);

      previewReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageListener, backgroundHandler);
      previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewReader.getSurface());

      // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
      cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
          Arrays.asList(surface, previewReader.getSurface()),
          new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
              // The camera is already closed
              if (null == cameraDevice) {
                return;
              }

              // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
              captureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
              try {
                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                previewRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                previewRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                    previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
              } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
              showToast("Failed");
            }
          },
          null);
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
    }
  }

   * Callback for Activities to use to initialize their data once the selected preview size is
   * known.
   */
  public interface ConnectionCallback {
    void onPreviewSizeChosen(Size size, int cameraRotation);
  }

 /** Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas. */
  static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Size lhs, final Size rhs) {
      // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
      return Long.signum(
          (long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() - (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
  }

  /** Shows an error message dialog. */
  public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public static ErrorDialog newInstance(final String message) {
      final ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog();
      final Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
      dialog.setArguments(args);
      return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      final Activity activity = getActivity();
      return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
          .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
          .setPositiveButton(
              android.R.string.ok,
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
                  activity.finish();
                }
              })
          .create();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.